# ASP.NET Core and Angular: Microsoft Authentication

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, facebook-login, google-signin, asp.net-core-identity

For the moment I'm trying to add third party authentication to my ASP.NET Core web application. Today I've successfully implemented Facebook authentication.
This was already a struggle since the docs only mention Facebook authentication for a ASP.NET application with razor pages (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/facebook-logins?view=aspnetcore-2.2).
Nothing has been written in the docs about implementing this for Angular apps.

This was the most complete walkthrough I found for ASP.NET Core + Angular + FB auth: https://fullstackmark.com/post/13/jwt-authentication-with-aspnet-core-2-web-api-angular-5-net-core-identity-and-facebook-login

I'm using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity, this package already manages a lot for you. But I can't find how to get started implementing Microsoft, Google or even Twitter login in a web app. The docs don't seem to cover that part...

My GitHub repo: https://github.com/MusicDemons/MusicDemons-ASP-NET

Anyone had any experience with this?

Comment: You may find some value in this: https://www.blinkingcaret.com/2018/07/18/secure-an-asp-net-core-web-api-using-cookies/

Comment: No that's about how to create a cookie from Angular through ASP.NET Core. I'm trying to enable the visitor of the website to login using Facebook, Microsoft, Google, Twitter, LinkedIn, instead of creating an account in my database. I've uploaded a demo at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PLTaHdAKBOo which demonstrates a working login using Facebook. I want to also implement Google-login and Microsoft-login (modify the resolution to 1080px)

Comment: just take a look to the microsoft documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: Wouldn't you think one would already have done that? The docs aren't complete by far. Anyway I already managed to get it working well

Answer (score 7, accepted):

google-login.component.html

```
<button class="btn btn-secondary google-login-btn" [disabled]="isOpen" (click)="launchGoogleLogin()">
    <i class="fa fa-google"></i>
    Login with Google
</button>
```

google-login.component.scss

```
.google-login-btn {
    background: #fff;
    color: #333;
    padding: 5px 10px;

    &:not([disabled]):hover {
      background: #eee;
    }
}
```

google-login.component.ts

```
import { Component, Output, EventEmitter, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../../../services/auth.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginResult } from '../../../entities/loginResult';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-google-login',
  templateUrl: './google-login.component.html',
  styleUrls: [
    './google-login.component.scss'
  ]
})
export class GoogleLoginComponent {

  private authWindow: Window;
  private isOpen: boolean = false;

  @Output() public LoginSuccessOrFailed: EventEmitter<LoginResult> = new EventEmitter();

  launchGoogleLogin() {
    this.authWindow = window.open(`${this.baseUrl}/api/Account/connect/Google`, null, 'width=600,height=400');
    this.isOpen = true;
    var timer = setInterval(() => {
      if (this.authWindow.closed) {
        this.isOpen = false;
        clearInterval(timer);
      }
    });
  }

  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router, @Inject('BASE_URL') private baseUrl: string) {
    if (window.addEventListener) {
      window.addEventListener("message", this.handleMessage.bind(this), false);
    } else {
      (<any>window).attachEvent("onmessage", this.handleMessage.bind(this));
    }
  }

  handleMessage(event: Event) {
    const message = event as MessageEvent;
    // Only trust messages from the below origin.
    if (message.origin !== "https://localhost:44385") return;
    // Filter out Augury
    if (message.data.messageSource != null)
      if (message.data.messageSource.indexOf("AUGURY_") > -1) return;
    // Filter out any other trash
    if (message.data == "") return;

    const result = <LoginResult>JSON.parse(message.data);
    if (result.platform == "Google") {
      this.authWindow.close();
      this.LoginSuccessOrFailed.emit(result);
    }
  }
}
```

auth.service.ts

```
import { Injectable, Inject } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from "@angular/common/http";
import { RegistrationData } from "../helpers/registrationData";
import { User } from "../entities/user";
import { LoginResult } from "../entities/loginResult";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class AuthService {
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient, @Inject('BASE_URL') private baseUrl: string) {
  }

  public getToken() {
    return localStorage.getItem('auth_token');
  }

  public register(data: RegistrationData) {
    return this.httpClient.post(`${this.baseUrl}/api/account/register`, data);
  }

  public login(email: string, password: string) {
    return this.httpClient.post<LoginResult>(`${this.baseUrl}/api/account/login`, { email, password });
  }

  public logout() {
    return this.httpClient.post(`${this.baseUrl}/api/account/logout`, {});
  }

  public loginProviders() {
    return this.httpClient.get<string[]>(`${this.baseUrl}/api/account/providers`);
  }

  public currentUser() {
    return this.httpClient.get<User>(`${this.baseUrl}/api/account/current-user`);
  }
}
```

AccountController.cs

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    private IEmailSender emailSender;
    private IAccountRepository accountRepository;
    private IConfiguration configuration;
    private IAuthenticationSchemeProvider authenticationSchemeProvider;
    public AccountController(IConfiguration configuration, IEmailSender emailSender, IAuthenticationSchemeProvider authenticationSchemeProvider, IAccountRepository accountRepository)
    {
        this.configuration = configuration;
        this.emailSender = emailSender;
        this.accountRepository = accountRepository;
        this.authenticationSchemeProvider = authenticationSchemeProvider;
    }

    ...

    [HttpPost("login")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody]LoginVM loginVM)
    {
        var login_result = await accountRepository.LocalLogin(loginVM.Email, loginVM.Password, true);
        return Ok(login_result);
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpGet("providers")]
    public async Task<List<string>> Providers()
    {
        var result = await authenticationSchemeProvider.GetRequestHandlerSchemesAsync();
        return result.Select(s => s.DisplayName).ToList();
    }


    [HttpGet("connect/{provider}")]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLogin(string provider, string returnUrl = null)
    {
        var redirectUrl = Url.Action(nameof(ExternalLoginCallback), "Account", new { provider });
        var properties = accountRepository.ConfigureExternalAuthenticationProperties(provider, redirectUrl);
        return Challenge(properties, provider);
    }

    [HttpGet("connect/{provider}/callback")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback([FromRoute]string provider)
    {
        var model = new TokenMessageVM();
        try
        {
            var login_result = await accountRepository.PerfromExternalLogin();
            if(login_result.Status)
            {
                model.AccessToken = login_result.Token;
                model.Platform = login_result.Platform;
                return View(model);
            }
            else
            {
                model.Error = login_result.Error;
                model.ErrorDescription = login_result.ErrorDescription;
                model.Platform = login_result.Platform;
                return View(model);
            }
        }
        catch (OtherAccountException other_account_ex)
        {
            model.Error = "Could not login";
            model.ErrorDescription = other_account_ex.Message;
            model.Platform = provider;
            return View(model);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            model.Error = "Could not login";
            model.ErrorDescription = "There was an error with your social login";
            model.Platform = provider;
            return View(model);
        }
    }
}
```

Stuff that matters in the AccountRepository

```
public interface IAccountRepository
{
    ...
    Task<LoginResult> LocalLogin(string email, string password, bool remember);
    Task Logout();

    Task<User> GetUser(string id);
    Task<User> GetCurrentUser(ClaimsPrincipal userProperty);
    Task<List<User>> GetUsers();

    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationProperties ConfigureExternalAuthenticationProperties(string provider, string redirectUrl);
    Task<LoginResult> PerfromExternalLogin();
}
```

Implementation

```
public class AccountRepository : IAccountRepository
{
    private YourDbContext your_db_context;
    private UserManager<Entities.User> user_manager;
    private SignInManager<Entities.User> signin_manager;
    private FacebookOptions facebookOptions;
    private JwtIssuerOptions jwtIssuerOptions;
    private IEmailSender email_sender;
    public AccountRepository(
        IEmailSender email_sender,
        UserManager<Entities.User> user_manager,
        SignInManager<Entities.User> signin_manager,
        IOptions<FacebookOptions> facebookOptions,
        IOptions<JwtIssuerOptions> jwtIssuerOptions,
        YourDbContext your_db_context)
    {
        this.user_manager = user_manager;
        this.signin_manager = signin_manager;
        this.email_sender = email_sender;
        this.your_db_context = your_db_context;
        this.facebookOptions = facebookOptions.Value;
        this.jwtIssuerOptions = jwtIssuerOptions.Value;
    }

    ...

    public async Task<LoginResult> LocalLogin(string email, string password, bool remember)
    {
        var user = await user_manager.FindByEmailAsync(email);
        var result = await signin_manager.PasswordSignInAsync(user, password, remember, false);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            return new LoginResult {
                Status = true,
                Platform = "local",
                User = ToDto(user),
                Token = CreateToken(email)
            };
        }
        else
        {
            return new LoginResult {
                Status = false,
                Platform = "local",
                Error = "Login attempt failed",
                ErrorDescription = "Username or password incorrect"
            };
        }
    }

    public async Task Logout()
    {
        await signin_manager.SignOutAsync();
    }

    private string CreateToken(string email)
    {
        var token_descriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
        {
            Issuer = jwtIssuerOptions.Issuer,
            IssuedAt = jwtIssuerOptions.IssuedAt,
            Audience = jwtIssuerOptions.Audience,
            NotBefore = DateTime.UtcNow,
            Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(7),
            Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new[]
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, email)
            }),
            SigningCredentials = jwtIssuerOptions.SigningCredentials
        };
        var token_handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        var token = token_handler.CreateToken(token_descriptor);
        var str_token = token_handler.WriteToken(token);
        return str_token;
    }
    private string CreateToken(ExternalLoginInfo info)
    {
        var identity = (ClaimsIdentity)info.Principal.Identity;

        var token_descriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
        {
            Issuer = jwtIssuerOptions.Issuer,
            IssuedAt = jwtIssuerOptions.IssuedAt,
            Audience = jwtIssuerOptions.Audience,
            NotBefore = DateTime.UtcNow,
            Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(7),
            Subject = identity,
            SigningCredentials = jwtIssuerOptions.SigningCredentials
        };
        var token_handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        var token = token_handler.CreateToken(token_descriptor);
        var str_token = token_handler.WriteToken(token);
        return str_token;
    }

    public Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationProperties ConfigureExternalAuthenticationProperties(string provider, string redirectUrl)
    {
        var properties = signin_manager.ConfigureExternalAuthenticationProperties(provider, redirectUrl);
        return properties;
    }

    public async Task<LoginResult> PerfromExternalLogin()
    {
        var info = await signin_manager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
        if (info == null)
            throw new UnauthorizedAccessException();

        var user = await user_manager.FindByLoginAsync(info.LoginProvider, info.ProviderKey);
        if(user == null)
        {
            string username = info.Principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Name);
            string email = info.Principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email);

            var new_user = new Entities.User
            {
                UserName = username,
                FacebookId = null,
                Email = email,
                PictureUrl = null
            };
            var id_result = await user_manager.CreateAsync(new_user);
            if (!id_result.Succeeded)
            {
                // User creation failed, probably because the email address is already present in the database
                if (id_result.Errors.Any(e => e.Code == "DuplicateEmail"))
                {
                    var existing = await user_manager.FindByEmailAsync(email);
                    var existing_logins = await user_manager.GetLoginsAsync(existing);

                    if (existing_logins.Any())
                    {
                        throw new OtherAccountException(existing_logins);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw new Exception("Could not create account from social profile");
                    }
                }
            }
            await user_manager.AddLoginAsync(user, new UserLoginInfo(info.LoginProvider, info.ProviderKey, info.ProviderDisplayName));
            user = new_user;
        }

        var result = await signin_manager.ExternalLoginSignInAsync(info.LoginProvider, info.ProviderKey, isPersistent: false, bypassTwoFactor: true);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            return new LoginResult {
                Status = true,
                Platform = info.LoginProvider,
                User = ToDto(user),
                Token = CreateToken(info)
            };
        }
        else if (result.IsLockedOut)
        {
            throw new UnauthorizedAccessException();
        }
        else
        {
            throw new UnauthorizedAccessException();
        }
    }
}
```

And finally the view that handles the callback and sends the message back to the main browser window (Views/Account/ExternalLoginCallback)

```
@model Project.Web.ViewModels.Account.TokenMessageVM
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Bezig met verwerken...</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <script src="/util/util.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        // if we don't receive an access token then login failed and/or the user has not connected properly
        var accessToken = "@Model.AccessToken";
        var message = {};
        if (accessToken) {
            message.status = true;
            message.platform = "@Model.Platform";

            message.token = accessToken;
        } else {
            message.status = false;
            message.platform = "@Model.Platform";

            message.error = "@Model.Error";
            message.errorDescription = "@Model.ErrorDescription";
        }
        window.opener.postMessage(JSON.stringify(message), "https://localhost:44385");
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

ViewModel:

```
public class TokenMessageVM
{
    public string AccessToken { get; set; }
    public string Platform { get; set; }

    public string Error { get; set; }
    public string ErrorDescription { get; set; }
}
```

Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    var connection_string = @"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=DbName;Trusted_Connection=True;ConnectRetryCount=0";
        services
            .AddDbContext<YourDbContext>(
                options => options.UseSqlServer(connection_string, b => b.MigrationsAssembly("EntitiesProjectAssembly"))
            )

    var connection_string = @"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=DbName;Trusted_Connection=True;ConnectRetryCount=0";

    var app_settings = new Data.Helpers.JwtIssuerOptions();
    Configuration.GetSection(nameof(Data.Helpers.JwtIssuerOptions)).Bind(app_settings);

    services
        .AddDbContext<YourDbContext>(
            options => options.UseSqlServer(connection_string, b => b.MigrationsAssembly("EntitiesProjectAssembly"))
        )
        .AddScoped<IAccountRepository, AccountRepository>()
        .AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>()
        .AddMvc()
        .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

    services
        .AddIdentity<Data.Entities.User, Data.Entities.Role>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<YourDbContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

    services.AddDataProtection();
    services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
    {
        // Password settings
        options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
        options.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
        options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
        options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
        options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
        options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 6;

        // Lockout settings
        options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = System.TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
        options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 10;
        options.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;

        // User settings
        options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
        options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters = string.Empty;
    })
    .Configure<Data.Helpers.JwtIssuerOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.Issuer = app_settings.Issuer;
        options.Audience = app_settings.Audience;
        options.SigningCredentials = app_settings.SigningCredentials;
    })
    .ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
    {
        // Cookie settings
        options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
        options.Cookie.Expiration = System.TimeSpan.FromDays(150);
        // If the LoginPath isn't set, ASP.NET Core defaults 
        // the path to /Account/Login.
        options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
        // If the AccessDeniedPath isn't set, ASP.NET Core defaults 
        // the path to /Account/AccessDenied.
        options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Account/AccessDenied";
        options.SlidingExpiration = true;
    });

    services.AddAuthentication()
        .AddFacebook(options => {
            options.AppId = Configuration["FacebookAuthSettings:AppId"];
            options.AppSecret = Configuration["FacebookAuthSettings:AppSecret"];
        })
        .AddMicrosoftAccount(options => {
            options.ClientId = Configuration["MicrosoftAuthSettings:AppId"];
            options.ClientSecret = Configuration["MicrosoftAuthSettings:AppSecret"];
        })
        .AddGoogle(options => {
            options.ClientId = Configuration["GoogleAuthSettings:AppId"];
            options.ClientSecret = Configuration["GoogleAuthSettings:AppSecret"];
        })
        .AddTwitter(options => {
            options.ConsumerKey = Configuration["TwitterAuthSettings:ApiKey"];
            options.ConsumerSecret = Configuration["TwitterAuthSettings:ApiSecret"];
            options.RetrieveUserDetails = true;
        })
        .AddLinkedin(options => {
            options.ClientId = Configuration["LinkedInAuthSettings:AppId"];
            options.ClientSecret = Configuration["LinkedInAuthSettings:AppSecret"];
        })
        .AddGitHub(options => {
            options.ClientId = Configuration["GitHubAuthSettings:AppId"];
            options.ClientSecret = Configuration["GitHubAuthSettings:AppSecret"];
        })
        .AddPinterest(options => {
            options.ClientId = Configuration["PinterestAuthSettings:AppId"];
            options.ClientSecret = Configuration["PinterestAuthSettings:AppSecret"];
        });

    ...
}
```

It's also worth mentioning that you have to get permissions from the social-media sites:

- Facebook: https://developers.facebook.com

  - Products -> facebook logins -> Add an OAuth redirect URI: this is the uri of your application (= https://localhost:44385/signin-facebook)
  - The user must set the option that he wants his email address to be shared with apps
- Twitter: https://developer.twitter.com/en/apps

  - Open app details
  - Enable Sign in with Twitter
  - Callback urls: https://localhost:44385/signin-twitter
  - Keys and tokens: generate those
  - Permissions: Request email address
  - You have to add the option in c#: `options.RetrieveUserDetails = true;`
- Google: https://console.developers.google.com/apis

  - You have to enable the Google+ API and People API
  - Signin credentials

    - Create credentials -> Client-ID OAuth -> Webapp
    - Authorized javascript sources: https://localhost:44385
    - Authorized redirect URIs: https://localhost:44385/signin-google
    - Copy the Client-ID and secret
  - OAuth-permissions

    - Bereiken voor Google API's: Is automatically set to email, profile and openid
    - Authorized domains: a public domain where you intend to host your website
  - Microsoft: https://apps.dev.microsoft.com

    - Converged applications -> add
    - Add platform -> Web
    - Redirect URLs: https://localhost:44385/signin-microsoft
    - Microsoft Graph Permissions: User.Read
  - GitHub:

    - The user has to set a public email address: Settings -> profile -> Public email

Comment: Trying to recreate your solution, there are quite some missing pieces in your code.
Do you have a public repo somewhere with a working example?

Comment: I'll create one

Comment: I've created an example project here: https://github.com/MintPlayer/ExternalAuthentication

Comment: Fabulous! I wanna give you money for this haha. Thanks a ton, mate, cheers! I've been working on a new project with ASP.NET Core 3.1 Web API + Identity + Angular 9. I've been trying to set up external logins with Google but I didn't know how to make the redirect etc. work properly in a REST API flow. A razor view to the rescue, brilliant. Thank you!

Comment: I have to note that for my Angular app I switched to Identity-cookie auth. Storing the bearer token in localStorage is not a secure way, since every script you include in your webpage (like jquery.min.js, angular.min.js, bootstrap.min.js) can read the user's localStorage for your website. But I'm still using the razor view to pass the login status/message to the angular app. https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer/tree/master/MP.Web